# Where do I fetch initial data from server in a React Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've started learning React / Redux and stumbled on something that is probably a very basic question. Below are snippets from my app with some code removed for simplicity sake.

My state is described by an array of sites which is empty by default. Later reducer will have `LOAD_SITES` action to load a different set of sites whenever user paginates to a different page but for now it's doing nothing. React starts by rendering `PublishedSitesPage` which then renders `PublishedSitesBox` which then loops over data and renders individual sites.

What I want to do is have it render everything with the default empty array and meanwhile initiate a "load sites from server" promise and once it resolves, dispatch `LOAD_SITES` action. What is the best way to make this call? I was thinking about either constructor of `PublishedSitesBox` or perhaps `componentDidMount`. But not sure if this would work - my concern is that I'll create an endless loop this way that will keep re-rendering. I guess I could prevent this endless loop in some way by having some other state param along the lines of "haveRequestedInitialData". Another idea I had is to simply make this promise right after doing `ReactDOM.render()`. What is the best and cleanest way to do this?

```
export default function sites(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
...

const publishedSitesPageReducer = combineReducers({
  sites
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(publishedSitesPageReducer)}>
    <PublishedSitesPage />
  </Provider>,
  this.$view.find('.js-published-sites-result-target')[0]
);

...

export default function PublishedSitesPage() {
  return (
    <PublishedSitesBox/>
  );
}

...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { sites: state.sites };
}

const PublishedSitesBox = connect(mapStateToProps)(({sites}) => {
  // render sites
});
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's no reason for this data load logic to touch your React components at all. What you want here is for the return of the promise to dispatch an action to your reducers, which make the appropriate changes to the store, which then causes the React components to re-render as appropriate.

(It doesn't matter whether you kick off the async call before or after you call ReactDOM.render; the promise will work either way)

Something like this:

```
var store = createStore(publishedSitesPageReducer);

someAsyncCall().then(function(response) {
  store.dispatch(someActionCreator(response));
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PublishedSitesPage />
  </Provider>,
  this.$view.find('.js-published-sites-result-target')[0]
);
```

Your React components are consumers of your store, but there's no rule that they need to be the ONLY consumers of  your store.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that makes sense and this has been one of the ways I was contemplating to go with but wasn't sure whether it was the intended way of doing it or whether there was some kind of "fetch default state" magic hidden in react/redux framework somewhere. Will try it out tomorrow and see if it works and looks well!

Comment: One of the awesome things about a a Redux store is that it can actually be the common clearinghouse for data from a variety of places. For instance, web sockets to remote live data sources can be dispatching actions that update your store without any user input, and your UI doesn't need to know or care where the new state came from.

Comment: Of course the action creator could do the async request instead.

Comment: Right - and then dispatch different actions on completion, depending on success or failure. At that point it's a matter of how you want to encapsulate - does it make sense for the store to understand where this data comes from and how to get it, or is that someone else's problem and it only cares about using it? (Depends on your domain; IMHO, either answer could be correct)

Answer (score -4):

There is a clear example here on how to do it : [Facebook Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

As for the endless loop, Once your array is no longer empty , Clear the Interval.
This should prevent the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have already read that tutorial and it's a very good one however it describes data fetching for React only. What I am trying to do is fetch data in an app where React is bundled with Redux, where data (app state) is supposed to be separated out from the React components.